# Very basic django tutorial producing error: TypeError at /hello/, hello() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, typeerror

I'm following this tutorial for django:
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/

And have followed every step to the word (I think). However, even the most basic Hello World isn't functioning.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(response):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from myproject.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
)
```

The server produces this error:

```
TypeError at /hello/
hello() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

This should be so simple but its just not working!

Comment: That should work - have you restarted your server?

Comment: "hello() takes no arguments" is inconsistent with the code presented.  Perhaps you have two functions named `hello`?

Comment: Thanks, restarting the server worked. Does this mean I have to restart the server for any minor change?

Comment: @S.Lott Yeah that's what I thought - I literally only have the functions that I've shown here.

Comment: Usually the development server restarts it's self when changes have been made, but I've also had it when I have to manually restart it like you had to. Using some IDE's with django prior to 1.3.1 don't auto restart the dev server either.

Comment: "Does this mean I have to restart the server for any minor change?" Depends on what server you're using to test.  What command did you use?  Include that in your answer, please.  Most of us use `manage.py runserver` to test.  It restarts automatically for most changes.

Comment: @MatthewRNYC: FWIW, `hello(response)` should be `hello(request)`. It doesn't *technically* matter, but views receive a request and *return* a response, not the other way around. It's best not to confuse the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that for *efficiency* it makes a lot of sense to not automatically reload all files for every request. Even just checking if any of them was modified is a rather costly operation for *production* servers. Sometimes you can enable this for development systems (see the manual if such an option exists). There are plenty of good reasons to not enable automatic reloading by default. In particular, too many people will then end up having it enabled on their production systems and complain about performance...

Another reason is that often interim states will be inconsistent, in particular when edits affect more than one file. Automatic reloading will then likely cause a error that could have been avoided by completing the edit, then reloading. (Still, this is not advisable for production systems to edit files online. But say, a synchronization process is running; you don't want your server to reload while it is still synchronizing.)

In some situations, tricks such as inotify on linux can be used to have the operating system notify the application for file changes. I guess the `manage.py` script will do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a `TypeError` in your view function, the view function has an argument mismatch.

1. Check whether it takes the required `request` is its first argument.
2. Ensure all keyword arguments from `urlpatterns` are in place.

Examples:

`url(r'^user/(?name[\w\-]+)/$', 'user')`

```
def user(request, name):
    #Your logic
```